# How to generate imported code with conflicting method and variable names?

Tags: python, xml, import, metaprogramming

I am working on a software which generates a generic Python source code through a set of inputs(methods and variables) by the user from a GUI. The source can also be saved in an XML with tags  and . Now I need to implement the import functionality through XML. While importing the user selects a new XML and all the functions and variables in the XML needs to be appended to the generated source. Example - 
XML Structure:

```
<functions>
def detect_obstacle(self):
    laserData = self.laser_scan
    for val in laserData.ranges:
        if val < 100:
            self.is_obstacle = True
            return
    self.is_obstacle = False
</functions>

<variables>
self.is_obstacle = False
</variables>

<interfaces>
LaserScan
</interfaces>
```

Generated Code -

```
from codegen import State

class Node():
    def __init__(self):
        self.is_obstacle = False
        self.laserScan = (Updates from a server thorugh a callback)

    def detect_obstacle(self):
        laserData = self.laserScan
        for val in laserData.ranges:
            if val < 100:
                self.is_obstacle = True
                return
        self.is_obstacle = False

class State0(State):
    def __init__(self, id, node):
        State.__init__(self, id)
        self.Node = node

    def runCode(self):
        if self.Node.calculate_obstacle():
            return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    node = Node()
    state0 = State0(0, node)
```

While importing the XML might have -

- similar name of methods and variables
- similar method names but different arguments.

Hence after importing and generating code, there would be ambiguity in the generated code. The current implementation is for Python and further, I would extend it to C++ too.

Strategies I thought of -

1. Name Mangling
2. Separate namespace or class for every new import.

What is the best strategy to implement the import functionality?

Comment: seems a risky task in any case, but why can't you just save the function code? why self.obstacle has to be in a class variable, not method arguement?

Comment: Sorry, the function would be directly saved, I just edited it. Also, yes the method can have argument obstacle, but just to develop a demo case I used obstacle as a class variable. There might be a case where class variable is needed.

Comment: what meaning do you attach to <variables> section? is it declaration of vars used in a function? confusing you do not have self.laser_scan there

Comment: All the variable under the variables xml tag would be generated as class variables.  Also self.laser_scan is autogenerated as there is one more tag in XML as interfaces which defines the interface to be used. In this case, the interface is Laser_scan hence variable laserScan is generated.

Comment: are you considering (3) exception on conflict of names?

Comment: Yes. Consider there is a state Move with a function sendSpeed() and variable speedX and speedY. A user developing a state MoveForwardAndLeft, would import XML of Move two times. In that case, there would be variable and method name conflicts.

Comment: `State` is not a great name for a method, it is counter-intuitive. I do not have an answer to your specific question about `MoveForwardAndLeft`. Generally, your task seems to be in the domain of [metaprogramming](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&ei=e5EbW-a_EoWOmgWd_JOoCg&q=metaprogramming+python+&oq=metaprogramming+python+&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i203k1j0i22i30k1l9.3492.4701.0.5119.8.8.0.0.0.0.171.766.6j2.8.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.8.765...0j0i67k1j0i22i10i30k1.0._C2EaUXDROw), in case it helps.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I'll look into metaprogramming.